# Conjecture: every set of $n$ equally spaced integers $\leq n^2$ contains a prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

My claim:

#### Any set of exactly $n$ integers in the range $[1,n^2]$ which are an arithmetic sequence and share no common factor will contain at least one prime.

Let $n\geq 2$ be a natural number, and let $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ where $1\leq a \leq n$ and $1 \leq b \leq n^2$, such that $an+b\leq n^2$. Then the set $\{ax+b \mid 1 \leq x \leq n\}$ will contain between $1$ and $n$ primes, inclusive.

**There *are* three exceptions:** $(n=12,a=1,b=113),(n=12,a=1,b=114),(n=13,a=1,b=113)$, but I strongly suspect those are the only ones. (You could eliminate them by requiring $a > 1$, but I don't think it's worth the cost in generality.)

In a nutshell, this conjecture claims that given an $n \times n$ square, any line you draw (that intersects the integers appropriately) must contain a prime, including for starters all rows and columns—something I called the Rook Conjecture, but have since seen referred to as the Calendar Conjecture.

I've empirically tested this out to $n=150$ or so, and the trend is strong enough that I'm almost sure it's correct. Of course, finding a proof is another story.

I'm looking for feedback. Good answers would be:

- counterexamples
- indicating that this is previously known and/or conjectured
- providing reasons why this does or does not seem likely to be true
- any other insights

Comment: Have you numerically tested it to some egregious number? I don't know much about number theory, but if you found a couple exceptions, I would be more inclined to assume there are infinitely many.

Comment: Minor terminology suggestion: call these sequences "arithmetic", rather than "equidistant". Coming from a functional analysis background, I'd instinctively interpret a sequence $(x_n)$ being "equidistant" to mean that $|x_n - x_m|$ is constant with respect to $m \neq n$.

Comment: Is $p$ in your exceptions supposed to be $n$?  We haven't seen $p$ before.  Why do you suspect it?  How far have you looked?

Comment: The exceptions in that specific region--the 113 to 127 gap, where $11^2$ and $2^7$ and $5^3$ all meet up--is obnoxious and in many cases a strictly one-off situation, so I'm not too worried about it.

Comment: Note that $2^7$ is not involved here because $127$ is a prime.

Comment: It would seem to me that $a=1,2,6,30$ and so on through the primorials would be the challenging ones.  $a=1$ is covered by the prime gap page of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap).  It is notable that the gaps get very small compared to the square root of the number, so it does seem likely you are right for $a=1$.  For $a=30$, for example, you can eliminate multiples of $2,3,5$ from consideration, which is why I suggested it is challenging.

Comment: It's known that every arithmetic progression $an+b$, $n=0,1,2,\dots$, with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ contains primes. There are standard conjectures as to how far you have to go to reach the first prime. There are also theorems about this, but the theorems are very much weaker than the conjectures. The theorem is due to Linnik.

Comment: See, e.g., https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178557/smallest-prime-in-an-arithmetic-progression

Comment: Was that helpful, Trevor?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is nonresponsive.

Comment: No, I'm not non-responsive. I upvoted helpful comments, including yours. There was no answer to mark correct, so that doesn't apply.